# How to expand list items without affecting other items. (flutter)

Tags: flutter, web, stack, row

I want to create the Netflix home page in flutter, and I'm stuck while creating this hover state.

[image]

I have created two base widgets. One for the number plus the thumbnail and the other one for the expanded view when the widget is hovered. Then I put them in a `stack` with an `Inkwell` where the `onHover` changes the state to show the expanded widget.

When I hover on the widget, it does switch between the normal state an expanded state, the problem comes when I try to put a list of these widgets together.

1. When using `row` (or ListView) to put them together, after hovering, the expanded widget makes the other widgets move. (which is not the wanted behaviour, I want them to overlap)

[image]

2. When I use it with `stack`, the widgets do overlap but now it isn't scrollable anymore.

[image]

I have added the link to the repo for anyone that wants to clone it and try running it themselves, I'm running it on flutter web.
https://github.com/Advait1306/netflix-flutter

**Widget with thumbnail and number:**

```
class TopListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  const TopListItem({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const double height = 250;

    return SizedBox(

      height: height,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SvgPicture.asset("assets/numbers/$index.svg",
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight, height: height),
          Transform.translate(
              offset: const Offset(-30, 0),
              child: Image.asset("assets/thumbnails/thumb1.jpg"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Expanded view widget:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HoverMovieTrailer extends StatelessWidget {
  const HoverMovieTrailer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const textTheme = TextStyle(color: Colors.white);

    return SizedBox(
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      child: Container(
        clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: const Color(0xFF242424)),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.asset("assets/backgrounds/background1.jpg"),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: const [
                      RoundIconButton(icon: Icons.play_arrow_outlined),
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                      RoundIconButton(icon: Icons.add_outlined),
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                      RoundIconButton(icon: Icons.thumb_up_alt_outlined),
                      SizedBox(width: 5),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: const [
                      RoundIconButton(icon: Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children:  [
                  const Text(
                    "98% Match",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 1)
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      "18+",
                      style: textTheme,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  const Text(
                    "4 Seasons",
                    style: textTheme,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 1)
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      "HD",
                      style: textTheme,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "Captivating",
                    style: textTheme,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Container(
                    width: 5,
                    height: 5,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.white54
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  const Text(
                    "Exciting",
                    style: textTheme,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Container(
                    width: 5,
                    height: 5,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.white54
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 5),
                  const Text(
                    "Docuseries",
                    style: textTheme,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  const RoundIconButton({Key? key, required this.icon}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.white)),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(icon),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Combining the widgets in the single widget:**

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:netflix_flutter/widgets/hover_movie_trailer.dart';
import 'package:netflix_flutter/widgets/top_list_item.dart';

class TopListItemWithHover extends StatefulWidget {
  const TopListItemWithHover({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TopListItemWithHover> createState() => _TopListItemWithHoverState();
}

class _TopListItemWithHoverState extends State<TopListItemWithHover> {

  bool hover = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: (){},
      onHover: (value){
        log("Hover value: $value");
        setState(() {
          hover = value;
        });
      },
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          TopListItem(index: 1),
          if(hover) HoverMovieTrailer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Lists:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:netflix_flutter/widgets/hover_movie_trailer.dart';
import 'package:netflix_flutter/widgets/top_list_item.dart';
import 'package:netflix_flutter/widgets/top_list_item_with_hover.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 400,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                itemCount: 8,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return TopListItemWithHover();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 50),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 400,
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.passthrough,
                children: [
                  for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
                    Positioned(
                      left: (i) * 300,
                      child: TopListItemWithHover(),
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So finally found the solution to this problem, the way to move forward is to use a stack in SingleChildScrollView.

A mistake that I made is, I did not set the SingleChildScrollView's direction to horizontal. So I added that.

And then one more addition that's needed is -- A empty sized box which has the width of sum of all the items in the stack.

```
          Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                width: 300*10,
              ),
              for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
                Positioned(
                  left: (i) * 300,
                  child: TopListItemWithHover(),
                )
            ],
          )
```

This finally expanded the stack to the required width and then made is scrollable also.

[image]